# Switching from the Main View to a different View

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, view, uikit, viewcontroller

I am attempting to use a button to go from one View (XIB) to another View. I'm using Xcode 4.3.2 and iOS 5.  I start off by creating the project (Single View Application).  I then create my button in Interface Builder, create my outlet in the header file, and my IBAction in the .m file.  Next, I right clicked on my project folder in Xcode and selected "New File".  I then selected "Object-C Class" and named it "SecondViewController".  Two new files were created, "SecondViewController.h" and "SecondViewController.m".  Then I went back and right clicked on my project folder in Xcode, selected "New File" and chose "view" out of the "User Interface" options.

Now I have my empty IBAction (my button) which I want to use to go to a new view, which is called SecondViewController.xib.

If the creation of the new XIB and .h/.m files are correct up to this point, then how would I go about doing this using my button to "get to" or display my second view?  Keep in mind, I'm still at a beginner level and I appreciate any help and your patience :)

The only differences I can tell between my main View and my SecondView are in the header files:

Main View header file:

```
@interface ButtonToNewViewViewController : UIViewController
```

Second View header file:

```
@interface SecondViewController : NSObject
```

IBAction:

```
-(IBAction)nextView:(id)sender
{
    // go to new view
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is quite a simple task that are covered by many tutorials online, but I'll give you some help anyways. :-)

First of all, when you create `SecondViewController`, remember to create it as a subclass of `UIViewController`, not `NSObject`. So unless you have done a lot of work with those files, you can just go ahead and recreate them. At the same time you can make sure that Xcode creates the xib-file for you automatically by checking a checkbox in the creation-process.

When you have created `SecondViewController` (.h, .m and .xib), open up `ButtonToNewViewController.m` and put `#import "SecondViewController.h"` at the top of the file. In your method `nextView:`, you can then use these two lines to change to the second view controller:

```
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
```

That should pop up the second view controller, with some simple animation. Make sure that the string you pass to `initWithNibName:` has the same name as your .xib-file.

And if you want to go back to `ButtonToNewViewController`, you can use this in a method in `SecondViewController`:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

That should clear things up a bit. :-)

Comment: I appreciate the help.  As I said, I'm very new to iOS development and I know how easy it is to get lost when searching online for "how to's".  This was perfect.  I appreciate you taking the time out to walk me through this process :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone returning to this question, the following syntax is now deprecated as of iOS 6

```
[self presentModalViewController: ]
```

The replacement is very similar

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change from one xib to another using the following.

```
- (IBAction)showInfo1:(id)sender
{    
    mySecondViewController *controller = [[mySecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nameOfMyXib" bundle:nil];
    [self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```